# Why can't I access crossdomain.xml file from tomcat server

Tags: tomcat

I am running tomcat6. I know i need to place my crossdomain.xml file in the webApps folder of tomcat. When I try to access the crossdomain.xml file via http://domainname.com/crossdomain.xml I get a 400 Bad Request error.

If I create a folder called xml in the webApps folder and place my crossdomain file in that folder I am successful at getting the crossdomain file with the following: domainname.com/xml/crossdomain.xml . Problem is I need the crossdomain.xml file to be at the root directory for Flash application to work properly.

Also, I cannot access an index.html file with domainname.com/index.html . But I can access the index.html file if I place it in a folder like so: domainname.com/html/index.html

This seems like a configuration setting in one of tomcat's config files. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue so I can access the crossdomain.xml file with: http://my_real_domain_name.tld/crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 5):

Tomcat's `webapps` directory is not what you see at the root URL in your browser, so putting a file into `webapps` will not make it available at `http://example.org/file`. Instead put your cross-domain policy into the `webapps/ROOT/` folder - which is Tomcat's default webapp. This should allow requesting it as you are trying to.

Comment: Thank you Axel.
Although your answer didn't solve my problem it gave me a better idea of what I should search for in google. 
Basically, I installed tomcat6 using:
yum install tomcat6
After doing this there was no ROOT folder in the webapps folder. I had to do the following:
yum install tomcat6-webapps
Which then installed the ROOT folder. I then placed my crossdomain.xml file into the webapss/ROOT folder and all is well.
Thank you again.

Comment: It also works with Tomcat 5.5
It's quite easy to mkdir ROOT and put the crossdomain file inside.
Thanks for the Tip Axel